# What is the space complexity of the python sort?

Tags: python, sorting, space-complexity

What space complexity does the python sort take? I can't find any definitive documentation on this anywhere

Answer (score 33):

Space complexity is defined as how much additional space the algorithm needs in terms of the `N` elements. And even though according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort), the `sort` method sorts a list in place, it does use some additional space, as stated in the [description](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listsort.txt) of the implementation:

> timsort can require a temp array containing as many as N//2 pointers, which means as many as 2*N extra bytes on 32-bit boxes. It can be expected to require a temp array this large when sorting random data; on data with significant structure, it may get away without using any extra heap memory.

Therefore the worst case space complexity is `O(N)` and best case `O(1)`

Comment: Well, you sure are sorting something that takes space in memory.

Comment: Yeah you certainly are, but space complexity is measured in additional memory needed so not the array itself. Nevertheless, I took a look at the implementation description and turns our they do use some more additional space for implementing the algorithm. My answer is updated accordingly

Answer (score 22):

Python's built in sort method is a spin off of merge sort called Timsort, more information here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort.

It's essentially no better or worse than merge sort, which means that its **run time** on average is `O(n log n)` and its **space complexity** is `Ω(n)`

Comment: ... that doesn't answer the question.