# find if point intersect in graph without sorting?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, optimization

I have a list of items that represents X,Y on a graph (all starts at point (0,0).
example:

```
1. [(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,2),(2,2)]
2. [(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,2),(2,2),(2,1),(1,1),(0,1)]
```

item 2 is invalid because it intersect at point (0,1).

in order to find if intersection exists, I sort (nlogn) the list and iterate to find if 2 points are the same.

```
def is_intersect(points ):
    # points  [(0,0)...]
    points.sort()
    for m,u in zip(points,points[1:]):
        if m==u:
            return True
    return False
```

My question:
is there a better way to find an intersection than the above algorithm (with space complexity O(1) no extra set or hashset)?

Comment: Seems duplicate of [Find duplicates in an array, without using any extra space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055508/find-duplicates-in-an-array-without-using-any-extra-space)

Comment: So an 'intersecting' list is simply one that contains the same point twice or more? I think you probably mean time complexity rather than space complexity? [Space complexity of python sort is O(n) or best case O(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759175/what-is-the-space-complexity-of-the-python-sort)

Comment: [Related](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.5555/1496770.1496815).

Comment: @pylos sadly it still uses extra space, because `points[1:]` makes a copy, too.

Answer (score 0):

There is an algorithm in O(n) time complexity and O(1) in memory
However it is based on the fact that the array elements are numbers, so you would need to create a function that transforms the pairs into numbers.

If the numbers are small and you know they are in a range [0,10^n). You can define the following bijection: `f(x,y) = x*10^n+y` 
From there use one of the approaches in [this post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-duplicates-in-on-time-and-constant-extra-space/) and adapt it to your needs.

Example:

```py
def duplicate(lst):
    return 12 #implementation of the algorithm in the post
def is_intersect(points):
  n = 1 #if you don't know what n is you can find it using the log_10 of all the numbers in the list and round up the maximum value 
  n = pow(10,n)
  for i in range(len(points)):
    points[i] = points[i][0]*n+points[i][1]
  ans = duplicate(points)
  if (ans is None):
    return None
  else:
    return (ans//n,ans%10)
```